# Android sourcecode download: Did I download one file multiple times?

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-source

I am downloading the source code of android via Ubuntu 12.04. And the manifest file is:

```
<default revision="refs/tags/android-4.0.1_r1" remote="aosp" sync-j="4"/>
```

So I am downloading android 4.0.1. But the things is I have downloaded 15G, but it is not finished yet...

There is some wrong with the university's network, it break down sometimes. Everytime it breaks down, the download stuck like this(at 88%):
[image]

It just stucks, so I need to stop it (ctrl+z) and repo sync again. 
And it will begin like this:
[image]

Because the stupid network, it stops at there(86%) this time:
[image]

5893, 86% VS 6005, 88%. It seems that it did less work this time than last time..
But the project file(it is hidden) is getting bigger as it downloaded, it is almost 16.4G now.

So I am really worried, did I just download one file multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AOSP is huge, and repo will do a good job of making sure all your projects are kept in sync. You may be downloading the same files multiple times, but the total space of the workspace will be correct at the end. My personal workspace can be anywhere between 25-40 gigs depending on my version of AOSP i am building for, and with my compiled files can go up to 80-90 gigs.

The problem with the download however is likely due to repo barraging your DNS server and you are ultimately getting denied. You might want to try using the [Google DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/) if that is possible for you on your network.

Answer (score 0):

I had same trouble with huge long downloads. I found a good tip at http://xda-university.com/as-a-developer/repo-tips-tricks ..

> We’ve seen that Android source is made of hundreds of project, each
>   project having it’s sources in its own git repository. With all the
>   Android versions jumps, those projects have evolved, and all that
>   history is still recorded in those git repositories. That means that
>   each of those hundred git repository will have several branches. So
>   the question is: do we really need to download (git-clone) all the
>   branches of every projects that make Android? Probably not.

I don't need to have access to multiple branches in a single tree, so I use this to pull down a tree and starting building it once the download is complete ..

repo sync  --current-branch && source build/envsetup.sh && echo "full_maguro-userdebug" | lunch && make